# Origin of the Asma ul Husna song and its arrangement

Tags: allah, asma-ul-husna

Assalamualaikum and Peace to all,

I was wondering what are the origins of the Asma ul Husna song/nasheed that is commonly taught today? Specifically in terms of its music/tune and its arrangement/'formula'.

Examples include
https://youtu.be/2iQD3Nm0F98
https://youtu.be/lXzyM36ZO9E
https://youtu.be/e-KygsbNVGk

but not, perhaps other takes on it that have other tunes or arrangements, such as https://youtu.be/tTao6LY05zw.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Arrangment of Asma ul Husna

The arrangement/lyrics of the 99 names of Allah were arranged by [Abu Hamid Al-Ghazali(1058–1111)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Ghazali&ved=2ahUKEwiY9PT8rIr7AhXkhv0HHSJwA28QFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0PR1vzAvffNeGQaJ1ipoCv)  in his book [Maqṣad al-asná(pdf)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ghazali.org/books/Ghazali-99-Name-of-God.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj4pvy4rYr7AhWGgv0HHVGZAiwQFnoECH4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1DFPfPpukVLuFiVNXZRLuo) published in *January 01, 1992*. You can see the arrangement on the tenth page of the link.

[image]

He did this arrangement based upon Abu Huraira report that Allah’s Messenger (ﷺ) said:

> Allah has ninety nine names, one hundred minus one; and he who counts them all will enter Al-Jannah (the Garden Of Heaven), and Allah is “witr” (One) and loves the witr (i.e. odd numbers). [Al-Bukhaari, At-Tirmidhi, An-Nasaai, Ibn Majah]

---

### How the Asma ul Husna is read:

The asma ul husna are read according to the rules of Quran:
the correct pronunciation, movement, and how the words are connected and tajweed. These can be found in books of tajweed and noorani_qaida/Quran primer.

A simple example from the Quran is [59:23]:

> Huwa Allahu allathee lailaha illa huwa almaliku alquddoosu assalamualmu/minu almuhayminu alAAazeezu aljabbaru almutakabbirusubhana Allahi AAamma yushrikoon
>
> He is Allah, besides whom there is no god, the Sovereign, the Supreme-In-Holiness, the Safe (from all defects), the Giver-Of-Peace, the Guardian, the All-Mighty, the All-Repairer, the Sublime. Pure is Allah from what they associate with Him.

Similar is for Asma- ul husna/ 99 names of Allah will be pronounced according to the rules of Quran.

### Sound of Asma-ul-husna

The asma ul husna we hear today gets slightly changed, it may be a change of sounds/vocals for example a male, female, kid , group will all sound differently. A group of people singing will sound like a choir, a kid and a female will have higher pitch of sound than the pitch of a man.

### Tune/Music of Asma ul husna

There should not be any tune of instruments in asma ul husna except of duff. There may be humming sounds added.

### Addition of words

Asma ul husna can have addition of words such as in the fourth link, Allah ho Allah ho was added after each names or darood at the end by the producers/singers etc. These changes may be done to stand out.

Comment: Thank you for the info on the lyrics, as it were, of the Asma ul husna. Any ideas/leads on the first known instance of the tune/music used (apologies for imprecise terms there)?  Jzkllh.

Comment: @Abdul-KareemAbdul-Rahman There isn't and shouldn't be any tune/music of instruments in the asma ul husna as instruments are haram with the exception of duff. However I shall  further explain and elaborate my answer later.